# How migrate data from Laravel session file default to Redis

Tags: laravel, redis

I have an application that uses the Laravel File default session approach but is getting bigger and bigger each day, and my small storage from the server is getting 70% of its capacity.

So I want to migrate all my user's session data to Redis how can I make this work? Any help?

Comment: what have you tried so far, there are so many tutorials on how to use redis

Comment: Is not how to use REDIS, is like how I can get all my Session Files Data and transfer to Redis